# Specific image not compiling

Tags: graphics, compiling, include, eps

I am writing a dissertation which already contains dozens of images in eps format. All of them compile just fine. Except for this one:

I get the following error message:
**Unable to read an entire line---bufsize=200000. Please increase buf_size in texmf.cnf.
/user/textbin/dvips: ! unexpected eof in DVI file**

Let me first emphasize that I have encountered this error before. From my understanding, it means LaTeX cannot compile the image itself (usually because I've photoshopped the picture). I've always successfully managed to fix the problem by copy-pasting the image itself into a new blank image and re-saving it.

This time, no amount of copy-pasting into a new image works. This may be due to the fact that this image is *extremely heavily* Photoshopped.

Here's the link to the image itself:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tz8b3xhwplijiko/supernatural_photoshop.eps?dl=0

Can any of you successfully embed it in a LaTeX file?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The link to the image isn't loading for me...would you mind posting the image within the question?

Comment: The upload to my local DropBox does not work. Are you sure that the relevant file really is an `.eps` file?

Comment: I apologize, my Dropbox was taking its sweet time syncing due to a poor internet connection. The image is now up and running via the link I provided.

Comment: @morthicia: Thanks for fixing the Dropbox issue. I've downloaded your file and examined it -- it is a `DOS EPS binary` file, perhaps compressed, as far as I can say this is not understable by  latex

Comment: I don't know how it could be DOS? I work with Mac OSX and used Photoshop CS to produce the image. The only thing that differs with other images used in my dissertation is that this one was really heavily photoshopped. So I thought copy-pasting into a new jpeg then saving as eps would fix the issue, but it hasn't. I really need to use this image, how can I work out this issue?

Comment: try this version https://www.dropbox.com/s/eulvddjsdc7ftzr/supernatural_photoshop.eps?dl=0

Comment: DropBox upload after converting to EPS https://www.dropbox.com/s/2p71vg2qm867pxm/supernatural_photoshop_new.eps?dl=0

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : a gazillion thanks!! Your version of the image totally works. Could you kindly explain to me what you did, so I might be able to solve this problem myself in the future?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the original is EPS but it has a binary tiff preview at the front (as allowed by the format) the one I uploaded, I  just removed the preview in emacs.

Comment: Well, I used the `gimp` image program (should be available on Mac too) and imported your file and saved again as `.eps` file, with the provided standard options (i.e. I changed nothing at the options: `PostScript Level 2, Enhanced PostScript`. Gimp is freeware, by the way

Comment: @morthicia does photoshop allow you to save as EPS _without_ a preview?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, I noticed the TIFF, on a second glance using `file foo.eps`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : thanks David. For those of us (me included) who do not speak emacs, could you kindly explain what you did in layman's terms? Thanks…

Comment: I just deleted the region from the start of the file to the `%!PS` which marks the end of the binary image preview and start of the postscript code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : yes, Photoshop does give me that option to save without a preview. Is that what I should do?

Comment: @morthicia yes the preview is a binary low resolution image which word processors that don't know postscript can use as on-screen version of the image, just using the postscript for printing, but being binary data it makes arbitrarily long line...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : thanks for the explanation, you're a star!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : thanks for the explanation too, I guess one day I'll fully figure out what it means in emacs… ;-)))

Comment: @morthicia: Well, what I did is basically the same then with Photoshop, just not using the Preview option. (That is possible in Gimp too, but I never use EPS preview)

Comment: @morthicia Hi, Mrs. Addams, you are using the image of your daughter Wednesday (actress Christina Ricci) as your profile image? BTW, the image in the question uses pastel colors, a no-go for an Addams. ☺

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: that's because my friends alternatively nickname me both Morticia and Wednesday (my physique seems to conjure both images!). The H was added along because in 1994, my first email account was hotmail and Morticia with no H was already taken. I thought I'd spice it up by adding the H. There you have it, a wholly unrelated LaTeX reply, that will hopefully not be too frowned upon here. ;-))

Answer (score 2):

The file has a binary preview at the start. You can either delete it (everything from the start up to `%!PS`) in any reasonable editor, or re-save the image from the original application without a preview.

Answer (score 1):

The EPS is given as binary EPS file (DOS EPS binary file), a format, which allows the bundling of the PostScript section with a TIFF or Windows Metafile.
The first version of the [specification](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/5002.EPSF_Spec.pdf) seems to be written in 1985, the current version is 3.0 from 1992. This age explains the "DOS" a bit.

Unhappily dvips does not support this kind of file. Some time ago, I have written a converter to extract the PostScript (and other sections) of a binary EPS file, see [dosepsbin](http://ctan.org/pkg/dosepsbin), available in CTAN and packaged in TeX Live, and MiKTeX.

The command line:

```
dosepsbin --eps-file supernatural.eps supernatural_photoshop.eps
```

Then `supernatural.eps` is used in LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks. Just checked out your package and doc. How do you call the package? \usepackage{dosepsbin} ??

Comment: @morthicia It's not a TeX package, but a program. The command line is given in the answer. The program comes with documentation and there is also help on the command line: `dosepsbin --help` and `dosepsbin --man`.

Comment: @morthicia: I've converted the file to `.pdf` format with `epspdf` (a texlua scripts). Can I post it somewhere?

Comment: @Bernard `dvips` cannot include PDF files. It would need to be converted back to EPS. In the case of `pdflatex`, which supports PDF as image format, it can directly include bitmaps like PNG or JPEG with no need to convert to EPS in the first place.

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek: Actually, `epsdpdf` first converted the binary eps to a standard .eps (cropped), then I converted the latter to .pdf format.

Answer (score 1):

I did it a somewhat unorthodox way (I don't know if this is helpful to you or not):

I just did a screenshot of the image, and it looked the same as it did in the dropbox file. Then, I uploaded it (I use sharelatex.com) and used the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{Babylon}

\end{document}
```

And got the photo on a LaTeX document.

If this isn't an option for you (to screenshot it) I'll delete this answer, but I just thought I'd throw the idea out there. Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem with doing this (although it has the advantage of working for anything that you can show on screen in any application) is that you have no idea about any possible loss of resolution. The things may look identical on screen but if the original was a 1200dpi high resolution bitmap and the screendump is from a 600x400 vga screen, they certainly won't look the same when printed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, of course. It was mainly meant to be a "last resort" sort of option.